# SilverStripe File Title Translation

Tags: file, internationalization, silverstripe

Is it possible to translate the `File` `Title` for all files in the assets folder?

I installed the translatable plugin but there is no documentation for file translation in the i18n SilverStripe chapter or plugin documentation.

[image: CMS File Title field screenshot]

In my `ProductPage` I have a custom field for `File` upload:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab(
    'Root.Attachments',
    $uploadField = UploadField::create('Files', 'Dateien')
);
```

The files can be on the English and German website. I need to translate the `File` `Title` for each language.

I tried the following but when I change the `File` `Title` it changes for both German and English:

```
// Apply Translatable modifications
$this->applyTranslatableFieldsUpdate($fields, 'updateCMSFields');
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you want translated and what you have tried please

Comment: I updatet my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the Translatable module on our `File` class we must add the `Translatable` extension to `File` in our `mysite/_config.php` file:

```
File::add_extension('Translatable');
```

However, I do not think the Translatable module is currently working for files.

There was an error when accessing assets as the Translatable class tries to add fields to the `Folder` class, which causes an error. This has now been fixed in the latest version with this [pull request to fix the `Folder` error](http://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/pull/248).

The next problem is `Translatable` requires the object to have a `CMSEditLink` function. `SiteTree` and `SiteConfig` have a `CMSEditLink` function, but `File` (and `DataObject`) does not.

To fix this we can create a `FileExtension` to define a `CMSEditLink` function for `File`:

```
class FileExtension extends DataExtension {
    public function CMSEditLink() {
        return singleton('AssetAdmin')->Link('EditForm/field/File/item/' . $this->owner->ID . '/edit');
    }
}
```

To enable this extension we add the following to our `config.yml`:

```
File:
  extensions:
    - FileExtension
```

After all of this, we can create file translations and view our translation list on each file, but the translation file links redirect to the root admin screen. It seems the assets link will redirect if it has the `?Locale=` URL parameter set. This URL parameter is set by the translatable module.

So this still won't work after all that work.

Comment: I have submitted the pull request: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/pull/248

Comment: The next issue I have found is that `CMSEditLink` is a function on `SiteTree`, not `DataObject` or `File`. In the `Translatable` code there is a check to see if this function exists. This will never work on anything but Pages:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/blob/2.2/code/model/Translatable.php#L1117

Comment: I use the plugin for SiteConfig to and the translation is working. SiteConfig extends DataObject.

Comment: Yes, that's because `SiteConfig` has the `CMSEditLink` function: 
http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SiteConfig.html#_CMSEditLink

Comment: What we'll probably need to do is add a `CMSEditLink` function to `File` through an extension to define the CMS edit link for a file.

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting started with this then I advise you [read the docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/)

To answer to Whenever you create a Field then where you specify the title you need to use the [_t or internationalisation function](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/#the-t-function).

The _t function is what silverstripe uses for all of it's fields, so you only need to find the right Namespace and Entity name string for the specified function...

```
_t("Namespace.Entity","This is a string")
```

For the field highlighted it is in the Object `File` which is the namespace and the Entity is `Name` and you can see this in `framework\lang\en.yml`

To override this you create your own lang files in mysite or your module folder with the detail to override it like this...

```
en:
  File:
    Name: My New Name Title
```

Comment: i dont want to translate the label "Titel" i want to translate the text in the input field ...